# what are the input cases for the following requirement

Tags: unit-testing, testing

what are the input cases for the following requirement (should cover boundary values and equivalence class):

X can take values from 0 to 100 where X is a signed 8 bit integer.

Comment: Is it just me who failed to understand the question or there are other people too? Or are you not yet finished writing the question?

Comment: what are the input values should i need to derive for X ?

Answer (score 2):

Input values for a [boundary test case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_case) in this case are  -1, 0, 100, 101.

If X is unsigned then the "[equivalent class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning)" boundary test case should have as input: 0, 100, 101.

I am not sure if you want to the test the boundaries of number representation, in this case 8 bits. So you should also test for signed 127 or 128 and unsigned 255. But it depends on  representation of the [signed numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) .

Comment: so for both boundary test case and equivalent class inputs should be -1,0,100,101,-128,127 right? why 1,99 not included ?

Comment: @MSharathHegde Because that is not an integer and it would resolve to 2 assuming you store it in the integer.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman it is(X) 8 bit signed integer ranges from -128 to 127

Comment: @MSharathHegde Yes I was referring to the 1,99

Comment: @FlorisVelleman you mean 199 ?

Comment: @darlinton i had referred to ur comment on [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323084/equivalence-classes-test-values-and-test-cases). Since i don't have 50 reputation i can't able to comment there. In the comment you have derived D so that D<0, D>0, D==0 if these values are for EC. For BVA of D<0 D should be -1 and possible minimum value, for D>0 D should be  1 and possible maximum value and for D==0 what are the boundary values of D? Are my assumptions correct ?

Comment: @MSharathHegde You have too many questions in this one. First - 0,1,99,100 are all inputs for the same domain - which is the one where the function should work. so you don't need to test 1 and 99, because they are suppose to work as much as the boundaires 0 and 100. The second comment about the other questions, I didn't get what BVA stands for; EC I suppose means Equivalent Class. Anyway, you should create another question and detail it better. Try to draw a line with the domain values, like in wikipedia. I think you are getting it. =)